# Why do we need the tag "articles" if we already have "indefinite-article", "definite-article" and "zero-article"? If it's redundant why not delete it?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-cleaning

There are four tags about articles: [articles](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/articles/info), [indefinite-article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/indefinite-article/info), [definite-article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/definite-article/info) and [zero-article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/zero-article/info).

Could you explain to me please why the tag "articles" is needed if we have the other three tags?
In which situations should we use "articles" and simultaneously use no others?
Isn't it enough to have only three tags without "articles"?

Update:
As far as I understood, nobody knows why the tag "articles" exists.
If so and it's redundant, why not delete it?

Comment: I tend to use "articles" on every question that uses any of the other article tags, so it's in theory easy to search for questions about any article. (By the way, "a-the" is not used and will be deleted soon.) Not sure how this works in practice. I do think we have too many overlapping tags on ELL, but that's mainly a problem with tense questions.

Comment: @Laurel You're saying the reason of there being "articles" is that "it's in theory easy to search for questions about any article". Can this reason itself be enough for the existence of the tag "articles"?

Comment: Yes? Though because there's only 3 related tags, it's not quite as useful as a tag like "Marvel Cinematic Universe" on SFF, which has innumerable ever-increasing sub-tags (and itself is a sub-tag of "Marvel").

Comment: Probably the biggest problem here on ELL with tags is that there's not very many people who care to retag questions consistently, which greatly reduces their usefulness regardless of how good the tagging scheme itself is.